# How to make a 2D ndarray from 3D so that (100, 50, 20) is (100, 100)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I want to merge two dimensions (y,z) of a 3D array (x,y,z) into one. Each corresponding value from y should be copied next to z.

For eg. I have 100 frames of a video with coordinates of 15 key points in 3 dimensions. The array shape is (100,15,3). I want output as (100, 45), which is merging y and z as 15x3.

Comment: in which format do you have the data? numpy ndarray or list?

Comment: this is not very clear.  You want to reduce the data/dimension but you don't specify how.  There is not a unique solution

Comment: Please add a piece of code that you have worked on and the examples including input and the output

Comment: I have updated the description of the question. Hope that makes it clearer. Please let me know if you need any more information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `numpy.reshape`. It can be used to flatten dimensions selectively.

```
import numpy as np

mat_3d = np.random.randn(2, 3, 4)
mat_2d = mat_3d.reshape((mat_3d.shape[0], -1))
print(mat_3d)
print(mat_2d)
```

In this example, I'm using `(mat_3d.shape[0], -1)` as argument of `reshape`. It means that the first dimension must stay unchanged, but all the other ones must be flatten (-1 is extra sugar to let `numpy` infers the right size, but using `np.prod(mat_3d.shape[1:])` would be the same).
In such as case, Numpy first fetches values across the last axis (z here), then the second to last axis (y here), and so on and so forth in higher dimension.